# How to mock Globally decalared object in asp.net mvc controller unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, controller

I'm trying to write test case for asp.net mvc controllers. I have a controller class inside which I have declared a Global object like:

```
UserInfo userDetails = CommonHelper.GetAuthenticatedUser();
```

And I'm using the `userDetails.UserId` inside the controller method. As a result it throwing error since `userDetails` is Null.
Does any one know how to mock the globally declared object.

Comment: What does `CommonHelper.GetAuthenticatedUser()` do, i.e. how does it retrieve the authenticated user?

Comment: It simply gets `UserInfo` object

Comment: This is an issue with how you've created you app, you've tightly coupled the helper with your controller meaning you can't mock it. Having this method as static feels wrong to me. If it was a class that got instanciated when the controller was created then it would be easy to pass a mocked version into the controller when running tests

Comment: @matt_lethargic i completely agree ..but being new to asp.net mvc i have used this all over my project. So just wondering if dere is a work around

Comment: Personally I'd create a UserManager class (or something like that) and inject it into your controllers constructor.... You will have to do some reading... google ioc or dependancy injection. (I learned this stuff with ninject, but Unity if fairly simple these days)